# Makefile and GCC: how to detect if we're cross compiling from make?

Tags: gcc, makefile

Previously to detect that a cross-compiling is used I checked `gcc -v` output.
The line "Configured with:" usually have the options `--host` and `--target`. Thus the simplest way is to check if `--host` value equal to `--target` value. But looks like the options `--host` and `--build` are not mandatory to be there.
Is there any common way to extract either `--host` or `--build` values from GCC? Or may be there is an simpler approach to decide that a cross-compiler gcc is used?
Finally I need to have different compiling flags depending on that option.

Comment: How/where do you need to know and decide what flags to use? I would normally assume you define your compiler and its flags in one go as build configuration and not deduce one form the other. Perhaps having a little more background might shed some light on this.

Comment: Usually it works in the other direction. You want to cross-compile, so you look for a cross-compiler. If you already have the compiler, doesn't its name already tell you that it's a cross-compiler?

Comment: Let's imagine that compiler name is provided through environment variable, e.g. CC, as usually. And the name of the compiler may be hidden using e.g. symbolic link or it can have a name as native gcc (e.g. /usr/local/bin/compiler1/gcc). And let's imagine that I need to provide linker flag -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs for cross compiling since not all upper layer libs are in place on build system (sure they are in place on run system).

Comment: Wouldn't you use a sysroot for your target when cross building? I am sorry, but I would still presume you choose a target to build from and configure your build (compiler and flags) accordingly. Should you not also care what target is your cross-build for and set other flags (like machine specific configuration) as well?

Comment: Other flags are coming using CFLAGS environment variable from upper layer, like CC for compiler. Some our build agents are cross compiling for arm: both armhf and aarch64, some ones are native compiling for armhf and aarch64. For now the only thing which I need is to set `-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs` for cross compiling cases.

Comment: Looks like the only solution is to leave this job to upper layer and use LDFLAGS coming from there.